# Daylight Savings Time DST Finding Difference between two dates

Tags: java, dst

We are sent two dates from an external source as Strings. We then calculate the difference between the dates to see how many hours they worked.

Two times a year due to the time change -  Our calculations get wrong. We use Java.
How do you solve a problem like this?

The two dates come in a file as String and have the following format.
"2019-10-07 11:07 AM"

Comment: You now have two answers with fairly different approaches - if you could provide more details, e.g. sample data, expected output etc, that would make your question *much* clearer. (A [mcve] would be great - you say "our calculations get wrong" which suggests you've already got code - so provide that.)

Comment: @JonSkeet We are getting Date as simple YYYY-MM-DD format string. This does not provide any TimeZone information. This will make it impossible to know the difference between the two dates right? based on your explanation, I would not know which 1:30, the first or second occurrence. How can I change the solution? Alldates are in the same timezone but it does not include DST info.

Comment: @Marco: Right, so that's just a `LocalDate`. You don't even *have* a 1:30. Again, please provide *much more information* in your question.

Comment: "2019-10-07 11:07 AM" is the string we receive

Comment: @JonSkeet What is the best way(format) to ask them to send data so that I can handle it on my side? They can only send as String. But I can recommend a format.

Comment: That's really a different question, *definitely* one that shouldn't be in comments, and would require *much* more context before I could make a recommendation.

Comment: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions on how to ask good questions. Note that "2019-10-07 11:07 AM" isn't a date, for one thing - it's a date and time. Precision in this sort of thing really matters.

Comment: @JonSkeet Added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397254/what-date-time-format-can-be-used-to-handle-dst-in-java

Comment: Why did you add a new question rather than just editing this one to clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your input data is and precisely what you're trying to determine.

If you're just receiving the dates, represent them as `LocalDate` values - that's what `LocalDate` represents; a date without any associated time zone. You can then use `Period.between` to find out the difference between `LocalDate` values, for example.

However, if you want to actually work out an elapsed time between two instants in time, then you *do* need to take time zones into account - in which case you might parse into an `OffsetDateTime` or a `ZonedDateTime` (or perhaps directly `Instant` - it depends on your input data). You can find the elapsed `Duration` between any two `Temporal` values (such as `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`, or `Instant`) using `Duration.between`.

It's worth noting that if your input data specifies a time zone (e.g. Europe/London) and a local date/time, you will need to consider ambiguous local date/time values. For example, suppose the file is something like:

```
Time zone: Europe/London
Shift 1 start: 2022-10-31T01:30
Shift 1 end: 2022-10-31T02:30
```

Should that be one hour, or two? It could be either, because 1:30am happened twice in the Europe/London time zone on that day, as the clocks went back from 2am to 1am. You could even end up with data that seems implausible at first glance:

```
Time zone: Europe/London
Shift 1 start: 2022-10-31T01:30
Shift 1 end: 2022-10-31T01:15
```

That's entirely valid as a 45 minute shift, if it started at the *first* occurrence of 1:30, and ended at the *second* occurrence of 1:15.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to represent correct points in time that, once constructed, allow calculations independent of any assumed time zone is `ZonedDateTime`. Whats nice about this class is that you can create instances of it easily using your own idea of local time.  You just need to tell it what time zone you're in, and it will do the right thing for daylight savings time as defined for your time zone.  Once constructed, you can do date/time arithmetic on these objects without concern for time zone or DST state.

Here are the two simple cases for creating and subtracting two `ZonedDateTime` objects representing an 8 hour timespan, one that spans a DST change, and one that doesn't.  There is likely a way to do this with Java's date functions such that you never have to see and deal with the individual numbers.

Case 1: Worker works 8 hours that don't cross a DST point:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
        2022, 1, 13, 1, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.of(
        2022, 1, 13, 9, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(zdt, zdt2);
System.out.println(hours);
```

Result:

```
8
```

Case 2: Worker works 8 hours that cross a DST point:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
        2022, 3, 13, 1, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.of(
        2022, 3, 13, 10, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(zdt, zdt2);
System.out.println(hours);
```

Result:

```
8
```

Notice that if you forgot about DST, you'd think that for the second shift, the worker worked an extra hour.  But given DST, the two shifts were the same number of hours.

NOTE: I started from numeric representations of date/times because the question does not give examples of or otherwise specify the formats of the input strings involved.  A "correct" example that involved string parsing would need to assume a format that might be different than what the OP is starting with. The primary question here would be if and how time zone is represented in those strings.  Parsing a string to come up with a set of numbers and a time zone is a separate problem that has nothing to do with DST, so I leave that for the OP to figure out.  It is likely that you could use date/time parsing logic in the Java date/time library to directly arrive at a ZonedDateTime, again, dependent on the format of the strings.

Comment: "A good way to represent correct points in time that don't assume a particular timezone or DST state is ZonedDateTime" - no, definitely not. ZonedDateTime *does* have a particular time zone. You want to *remove* time zones from the equations.

Comment: @JonSkeet - maybe I didn't use the right words.  My point is that once you've constructed a `ZonedDateTime` object, you can forget about all notions of time zone.  Maybe I should say "`ZonedDateTime` represents a particular point in time that does not depend on the assumption of a time zone.

Comment: I don't think you *can* "forget about all notions of time zone" but you can let it do most of the work for you. And no, `ZonedDateTime` *does* depend on the assumption of a time zone - the time zone you specify! Compare that with `LocalDateTime` which really *doesn't* have any notion of a time zone. Even with your edit, I think it's definitely worth revisiting the wording at the start of your answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet - thanks for your feedback. It prompted me to get the wording right at the start of my answer.  Feel free to let me know if you still think I have it wrong.  What's more, I'd welcome your feedback as to if my two examples provide the practical information that the OP is looking for.

Comment: I still don't know why you're talking about "independent of any assumed time zone" - why not just say "performs calculations with that specified time zone"? If you want a type that *doesn't* involve time zones, you use `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` (or `Instant` of course). `ZonedDateTime` is useful when you know a specific time zone and want to use it.

Comment: The two dates come in a file as String and have the following format. "2019-10-07 11:07 AM"

Comment: What's missing from this discussion is an explanation that a zone identifier and local time stamp from that DST-observing zone is not enough information to establish the correct offset during transitions. Users shouldn't rely on the heuristics built into some `ZonedDateTime` APIs without understanding the corner cases that will yield surprising results for durations around DST changes.

Comment: @erickson - I don't disagree.  Have at it.  SO is a group effort, even on individual answers. - Oh..this is a closed question.  So I guess this is all fairly moot, yes?