# What Date time format can be used to handle DST in Java

Tags: java, dst

Our client sends us a start and end date-time in a text file as a String in the below format

2019-10-07 11:07 AM

All date-time is in one timezone. We calculate the difference between the start and end date-time to calculate the hours worked. The hours worked calculation goes wrong when the transition of daylight savings time happens.  They are not sending enough information for us to calculate correctly.

I am about to recommend that they send us more information so that we can address this issue. What is a good solution here? What date-time format should we recommend to them that will help us address the DST change and calculate hours worked correctly.

We use Java.

Comment: Do you know that single time zone?

Comment: "All date-time is in one timezone." - and do you know what time zone that is? (Is that part of the information your application has separately?) Fundamentally, if they provided a date/time with UTC offset, e.g. 2019-10-07T11:07:00+0100, that would give you all the information you need.

Comment: Our application runs in the Central time zone. All clients in same. So all dates time are in the Central timezone only.

Comment: By the way, you did a great job asking and responding to comments on this question. You included the right amount of background, and it is clear you took care to thoroughly understand your problem before asking. Thanks for respecting your audience this way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Getting it right is not obvious

They are telling you their local time, and you can infer the time zone (because "all date is in one time zone").

The basic calculation looks like this:

```java
ZoneId pacific = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
DateTimeFormatter local = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm a").withZone(pacific);
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-11-06 01:30 AM", local);
ZonedDateTime until = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-11-07 01:30 AM", local);
long hours = start.until(until, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
System.out.printf("%d hours elapsed%n", hours);
```

This prints "***25 hours*** elapsed." In the Pacific time zone, November 6, 2022, is 25 hours long, because when daylight saving ends in the autumn, the clock is set back one hour. If someone tells you it's 1:00 AM, you don't know if midnight was one hour ago or two.

## The default offset heuristic

What you really need is the offset, and you have to rely on some heuristic for that. By default, `ZonedDateTime` chooses one instant from multiple ambiguous local date-times [by selecting the earliest offset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneId-) (the "summer" offset).

## Specifying the offset

If that's not what you want, you can override the offset explicitly. For example, maybe you process these time stamps close to real-time, and you can guess what the offset should be based on the current time. Or maybe you know that these local time stamps are always processed in chronological order; by tracking the latest time you've seen, and noting if an earlier time stamp follows, you can detect the clock set back and change the offset.

The [`ZonedDateTime.ofLocal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofLocal-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneId-java.time.ZoneOffset-) and [`ZonedDateTime.ofStrict()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofStrict-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneOffset-java.time.ZoneId-) functions can be used to explicitly control the offset.

## OffsetDateTime

Alternatively, you might request that they include the offset in the timestamp string. Usually this would be indicated with a signed number of hours and minutes: "-07:00" or "-0800". This will provide unambiguous interpretation of times during DST transitions.

---

Here is an example using `OffsetDateTime`. First, if the offset uses a colon, as in "2019-10-07T11:07:00+01:00", it is a standard format, and can be parsed like this:

```java
OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-10-07T11:07:00+01:00");
```

If the colon is missing, you need a formatter to handle the non-standard input:

```java
DateTimeFormatter odt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    .appendOffsetId()
    .toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime when = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-10-07T11:07:00+01:00", odt);
```

From there, the calculation is the same as with `ZonedDateTime`:

```
OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-11-06T01:00:00-07:00", odt);
OffsetDateTime until = OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-11-07T01:54:00-08:00", odt);
long hours = start.until(until, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
System.out.printf("%d complete hours elapsed.%n", hours);
Duration duration = Duration.between(start, until);
System.out.println("Full duration: " + duration);
```

Comment: Thanks @erickson. I can recommend a change of date-time format to be used when they send us the date-time strings. WIll have them include the offset for accuracy. So they will be sent as - "2019-10-07T11:07:00+0100". How will I calculate the hours in that case?

Comment: @Marco See my update at the end. If you can choose the form with the colon ("+01:00"), you don't need a custom format to parse.

Comment: If I store the incoming OffsetDateTime in a Oracle Date column, would I lose the offsets. What's the best way to persist these dates?

Comment: @Marco I think `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is your best bet. I don't have Oracle set up to test corner cases and see how the driver handles conversion between `OffsetDateTime` and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, so you should verify behaviors around DST transitions, especially in the autumn. Beware that this data type is not portable across databases. I'm stuck with MySQL, and in the absence of a type that includes zone or offset, my preference is to store and index TIMESTAMP (a Unix or UTC time) and when I need to convert to local dates or date-times, store the zone name in another column.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple task. The [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class gives you all the info you need. 2019-10-07 11:07 AM Your format would be `'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a'` and you should use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. But since you need to take into account daylight savings time then you might want to use classes [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) or [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) and provide your timezone. It might be an overkill, but I once worked on the project where I needed to parse Strings to Dates without knowing the format in advance. So, here is the article I wrote on how to do that: [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/)